# create procedure with transaction in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I really need help, mysql is quite new. you need to write a transaction that checks if, if you insert data, the password length is 4 characters, then the transaction rolls back, otherwise the entry is inserted into the table. For implementation, we used the procedure

```
                         ` CREATE PROCEDURE PROC (@id int (11), @log 
                         varchar (45), @em 
                      varchar (45),
                      @pass int (45),@st int (11));
                      AS
                      BEGIN
                      BEGIN 
                      START TRANSACTION;
                      INSERT INTO user 
               (`id_User`,`login`,`email`,`password`,`status`) 
                VALUES(@id, @log, @em, @pass, @st); 
              COMMIT
              END 
              BEGIN 
              IF (length(@pass) < 4)
                BEGIN
                 ROLLBACK
                      END
                       END 
                       END`
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. It's not clear what exactly your problem is and where the issue happens. Please provide more details on that in your question. If you're receiving any error message, these would also help.

Comment: START TRANSACTION or BEGIN start a new transaction.

COMMIT commits the current transaction, making its changes permanent.

ROLLBACK rolls back the current transaction, canceling its changes. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want to do, you don't need transactions at all. Code you posted had commit before rollback, so even if password is less than 4 chars long insert will still happen and there won't be any transaction to rollback. Apart from that, you are using variables in wrong way. However, If this is how you are validating user input by not just adding any entry to database then it is bad practice. You should ensure that password less than 4 chars long can't be submitted from form.

Have a look below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc`(
    v_id int (11), 
    v_log varchar (45), 
    v_em varchar (45),
    v_pass int (45),
    V_st int (11)
)
BEGIN
    IF(LENGTH(v_pass) >= 4) THEN
        INSERT INTO user (`id_User`,`login`,`email`,`password`,`status`) 
        VALUES(v_id,v_log, v_em, v_pass, V_st);
    END IF;
END
```

Hope this helps.